# Why does Atom editor stop colorizing long lines of code?

Tags: atom-editor

Colors are working fine in atom, it detects the language even in mixed files (PHP, HTML, SQL, Scripts, CSS). The problem is that when lines are somewhat long, sometimes, not always, from a certain part towards the end of the line, the code appears without colors.

For example, the line inside the following PHP if statement stops showing colors after `planification_surt.name LIKE`, so the last part has no colors: `CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR planification_surt.name_x LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";`

```
if($mod == 'incX') {
    $queryX = "SELECT DISTINCT serious.id, serious.title, CONCAT(people.firstname,' ',people.lastname), serious.year, people.birth, people.death FROM people JOIN serious ON people.id = serious.people_id JOIN serious_planification_surt ON serious.id = serious_planification_surt.serious_id JOIN planification_surt ON planification_surt.id = serious_planification_surt.planification_surt_id WHERE planification_surt.name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%') OR planification_surt.name_x LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
}
```

Other similar cases are when I have a `<p></p>` in HTML with a very long paragraph. The closing tag `</p>` at the end does not appear red, like the opening tag `<p>` at the beginning. It is just without color. When between opening and closing tags the text is not too long, everything works fine, both `<p>` and `</p>` are displayed red.

What could be causing this?